# SublimeText - Unselect last incrementally selected element?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I recently discovered the insanely useful <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> functionality in sublime text. With a careful eye, it's almost as functional for things like renaming as far more sophisticated refactoring tools.

One thing bothers me. As I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> through my selections, sometimes I've selected 10 items and overshoot by one (eg. into another method). Is there a way to reverse direction and "deselect the last selected item"?

Comment: I just had this exact question. Thanks for asking

Comment: Also works for VS Code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> as per [sublimetext.com/docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html) and tested by me.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will skip the current selection.

Comment: No prob! I actually didn't know about the ctrl+d command before this. I'm definitely going to use it now!

Comment: I didn't know about Ctrl+d either, looks like I need to look into more shortcuts for sublime!

Comment: This feature is promising, until the moment when you select an element which is not the first in the document. Example : 
`notest
notest

test
test
test
test`

Let's say you select the first 'test' occurence. Hit ctrl D 4 times, then 'test' from 'notest' is selected, you cannot unselect it using ctrl+D, ctrl+K, it messes everything up. I can't get any logic in this.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can deselect anything while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Comment: @George you can un-highlight some region of already highlighted text this way: by holding Alt and dragging your mouse along that text with left-mouse-button pressed. here, i've made a little flash demo: megaswf.com/file/2557258

Comment: For fellow Mac users it is Just ⌘+shift + left click instead of 'alt'

Answer (score 3):

**For Mac:**

Skip last: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

Skip current: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Unfortunately though, when the "selection loop" reaches bottom of document and starts from the top again - the functionality is lost.