# How do I remove selection of a find next match in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode lets you add to your selection the next occurence of your current selection via the "Add Selection To Next Find Match" command (or Cmd/Ctrl + D shortcut).

Is there a way to remove the last added match from the selection? Basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411850/sublimetext-unselect-last-incrementally-selected-element) but for VS Code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok wow, so the same shortcut in the [answer for Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12412027/80428) works for VS Code:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>

Which invokes the `Undo cursor` command.

[image: Pressing Ctrl U undos the cursor selection]